# Fill new dataframe column using conditions after groupby using more than 2 column and 2 rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following table. I need to group by **Col1** , check if **Col2** contains Y,

if yes then create new column **Col4** and insert corresponding **Col3** in all  rows of **Col4**
if no then just coly **Col3** in **Col4**

| index | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | X | ABC |
| 1 | 1 | Y | XX |
| 2 | 1 | X | QW |
| 3 | 2 | X | VB |
| 4 | 2 | X | AY |
| 5 | 3 | X | MM |
| 6 | 3 | X | YY |
| 7 | 3 | Y | XX |

**Desired table**

| ------ | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | New_Col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | X | ABC | XX |
| 1 | 1 | Y | XX | XX |
| 2 | 1 | X | QW | XX |
| 3 | 2 | X | VB | VB |
| 4 | 2 | X | AY | AY |
| 5 | 3 | X | MM | XX |
| 6 | 3 | X | YY | XX |
| 7 | 3 | Y | XX | XX |

Comment: There is only one `Y` per groups?

Comment: No, it could be any number of Y per Col1 value, and those rows should contain their own specific value

Comment: So there is multiple `Y` per group, not only one?

Comment: In this case what do you want to do if there are multiple values per group?

Comment: Yes, and rest of Col2 values can take any Y value to fill their New_Col i.e first corresponding value to Y

Comment: Ok, so is possible change first in `Col2` to `Y` and add expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby_transform` after hide undesired values:

```
df['New_Col'] = (df['Col3'].mask(df['Col2'] != 'Y')
                           .groupby(df['Col1'])
                           .transform('first')
                           .fillna(df['Col3']))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   index  Col1 Col2 Col3 New_Col
0      0     1    X  ABC      XX
1      1     1    Y   XX      XX
2      2     1    X   QW      XX
3      3     2    X   VB      VB
4      4     2    X   AY      AY
5      5     3    X   MM      XX
6      6     3    X   YY      XX
7      7     3    Y   XX      XX
```

Step by step:

```
# Hide values
>>> out = df['Col3'].mask(df['Col2'] != 'Y')
0    NaN
1     XX
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
6    NaN
7     XX
Name: Col3, dtype: object

# Get the first value for each group (nan is the last value)
>>> out = out.groupby(df['Col1']).transform('first')
0      XX
1      XX
2      XX
3    None
4    None
5      XX
6      XX
7      XX
Name: Col3, dtype: object

# Fill missing values to default (Col3)
>>> out = out.fillna(df['Col3'])
0    XX
1    XX
2    XX
3    VB
4    AY
5    XX
6    XX
7    XX
Name: Col3, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter only `Y` rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Col1`, last replace non matched values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
s = df[df['Col2'].eq('Y')].set_index('Col1')['Col3']

df['Col4'] = df['Col1'].map(s).fillna(df['Col3'])
print (df)
   index  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0      0     1    X  ABC   XX
1      1     1    Y   XX   XX
2      2     1    X   QW   XX
3      3     2    X   VB   VB
4      4     2    X   AY   AY
5      5     3    X   MM   XX
6      6     3    X   YY   XX
7      7     3    Y   XX   XX
```

If possible matched value is `NaN`s solution is modified:

```
print (df)
   index  Col1 Col2 Col3
0      0     1    X  ABC
1      1     1    Y  NaN
2      2     1    X   QW
3      3     2    X   VB
4      4     2    X   AY
5      5     3    X   MM
6      6     3    X   YY
7      7     3    Y   XX


s = df[df['Col2'].eq('Y')].set_index('Col1')['Col3']

df['Col4'] = np.where(df['Col1'].isin(s.index), df['Col1'].map(s), df['Col3'])
print (df)
  index  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0      0     1    X  ABC  NaN
1      1     1    Y  NaN  NaN
2      2     1    X   QW  NaN
3      3     2    X   VB   VB
4      4     2    X   AY   AY
5      5     3    X   MM   XX
6      6     3    X   YY   XX
7      7     3    Y   XX   XX
```

EDIT: Solution if multiple `Y` values per groups - replace random value per groups by [`DataFrameGroupBy.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html):

```
m = df['Col2'].eq('Y')

s = df[m].groupby(df['Col1']).sample(1).set_index('Col1')['Col3']
df['Col4'] = df['Col3'].where(m).fillna(df['Col1'].map(s)).fillna(df['Col3'])

print (df)
   index  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0      0     1    Y  ABC  ABC
1      1     1    Y   XX   XX
2      2     1    X   QW  ABC
3      3     2    X   VB   VB
4      4     2    X   AY   AY
5      5     3    X   MM   XX
6      6     3    X   YY   XX
7      7     3    Y   XX   XX
```